# Is Google Datastore (Firebase in datasore mode) have limit write throughput for a new account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, limit, datastore

I have tested a while using multiple process, it seems that there is some kind of limit (around 2400 Write per seconds).

No matter I write into different entities, different kinds, or even different namespace, I can't go up higher for such limit.

Any one has ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Datastore limits are well documented here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits

But from the behaviour you seem to be limited by hotspotting:

> **High read/write rates to a narrow key range**
>
> 1. Avoid high read or write rates to lexicographically close documents, or your application will experience contention errors. This issue is known as hotspotting, and your application can experience hotspotting if it does any of the following:
> 2. Creates new entities at a very high rate and allocates its own monotonically increasing IDs.
> 3. Datastore mode allocates keys using a scatter algorithm. You should not encounter hotspotting on writes if you create new entities using automatic entity ID allocation.
> 4. Creates new entities at a very high rate using the legacy sequential ID allocation policy.
> 5. Creates new entities at a high rate for a kind with few entities.
> 6. Creates new entities with an indexed and monotonically increasing property value, like a timestamp, at a very high rate.
> 7. Deletes entities from a kind at a high rate.
> 8. Writes to the database at a very high rate without gradually increasing traffic.
>
> If you are using Datastore mode, you can get slow writes due to a hotspot if you have a sudden increase in the write rate to a small range of keys. Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode will eventually split the key space to support high load.

see: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices for more details.